# How to output multiple value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I need to output multiple value from my function and access to outside variable, put into input hidden and POST variable to enable access data from php.

The data came from user input value from multiple row table which is the multiple row count and other value gets from database.

Javascript;

```
function validateForm() {

$('textarea.pc_1').each(function(event){ 
      var thought= $(this).val();     
      $("input[name='status']").val(thought);
      alert(status.value);
  })
}
```

Javascript function above can alert multiple value but when value post into input hidden, only single value POST to pc1_process.php. All I need is output multiple value from this function and pass into input hidden. Access this value from POST on pc1_process.php.

pc1.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {

$('textarea.pc_1').each(function(event){ 
      var thought= $(this).val();     
      $("input[name='status']").val(thought);
      alert(status.value);
  })
}
</script>
...
...
<form name="myForm" id="contact" method="post" action="../lpc/pc1_process.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

<table id="tftable" class="MyTable" style="font-size:12px; color:#333333; width:100%; border-width: 1px; border-color: #729ea5; border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" >
        <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:#acc8cc;">
        <td style="font-size:12px; border-width: 1px; padding: 8px; border-style: solid; border-color: #729ea5;">Issues</td>
        <td style="font-size:12px; border-width: 1px; padding: 8px; border-style: solid; border-color: #729ea5;">Notes <br></td>
        <td style="font-size:12px; border-width: 1px; padding: 8px; border-style: solid; border-color: #729ea5;">Status <br></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php 
    if ($info6['datetime_submit'] != null){
    $alert_null = "";   
    $check11 = mysql_query("select *
    from    (
    select * from page1_table union all
    select * from page2_table 
    ) t
    where t.submit = 'No' AND t.userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'") or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check11)) {
        ?>              
    <tr style="background-color:#d4e3e5;">
        <td style="font-size:12px; border-width: 1px; padding: 8px; border-style: solid; border-color: #729ea5;"><?php echo $row["issues"];?></td>
        <td style="font-size:12px; border-width: 1px; padding: 8px; border-style: solid; border-color: #729ea5;"><?php echo $row["notes"];?></td>
        <td style="font-size:12px; border-width: 1px; padding: 8px; border-style: solid; border-color: #729ea5;">
            <textarea class="pc_1" style="border: none;border-color: Transparent;overflow: auto;width: 100%;height: 100%;background-color:#d4e3e5;resize: none; "></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <?php }

}?>
</table>

<br><br>    
<input type="hidden" id="status" name="status"/>
<input style="float: right;" type="image" <?php echo $disabled?> src=<?php echo $button_off?> onMouseOver="this.src='../images/submit_button_on.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='../images/submit_button_off.png'">
</form>
```

pc1_process.php

```
<?php
$status = isset($_POST['status'])?filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'status', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING):"";

echo($status);
?>
```

Comment: Can I suggest you rethink how you appear to be planning your validation. It would be better to post everything and validate it all in pc1_process.php as it reaches it. Have an array of key's you are expecting in your pc1_process file as well, do not allow validation of keys you are not expecting.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass it like this:

```
function validateForm() {
    var thought = $('textarea.pc_1').map(function(){ 
                        return this.value;
                  }).get();
    $("input[name='status']").val(thought); // <--this holds ',' separated values
}
```

so in the above code the `var thought` holds an array of values like `['val1', 'val2', ...n]` so now setting those values to the `$("input[name='status']")`.

---

`.map()` is having some issues in `ie 6, 7, 8` versions so you can do like below:

```
function validateForm() {
    var thought = [];
    $('textarea.pc_1').each(function(){ 
         thought.push(this.value);
    });
    $("input[name='status']").val(thought); // <--this holds ',' separated values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to create multiple hidden variable with unique name or name attribute of input field should be an array(name='status[]') or append the value of textarea in same hidden variable by having some unique identifier so that you can explode them to have value of each.

If you set input name as array then you will have all values in array in php script like $_POST['status']

In above JS function you are assigning value to hidden variable so I think you are getting only last value in PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you copying your textarea content into a hidden field?

If you add a `name` attribute to your textareas you can access those names in the PHP. Additionally, if you give each textarea the same name, but with `[]` at the end of the name, you can access the textarea values as an array:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check11)) {
?>              
<tr style="background-color:#d4e3e5;">
    <td style="font-size:12px; border-width: 1px; padding: 8px; border-style: solid; border-color: #729ea5;"><?php echo $row["issues"];?></td>
    <td style="font-size:12px; border-width: 1px; padding: 8px; border-style: solid; border-color: #729ea5;"><?php echo $row["notes"];?></td>
    <td style="font-size:12px; border-width: 1px; padding: 8px; border-style: solid; border-color: #729ea5;">
        <textarea name="status[]" class="pc_1" style="border: none;border-color: Transparent;overflow: auto;width: 100%;height: 100%;background-color:#d4e3e5;resize: none; "></textarea>
    </td>
</tr> 
<?php }
```

pc1_process.php

```
<?php
$all_statuses = '';
if (isset($_POST['status'])) {
    foreach($_POST['status'] as $status) {
        // Add filtering here
        $all_statuses .= $status;
    }
}
echo($all_statuses);
?>
```